# extract some character from a field

Tags: mysql

I have for example this field:

```
Pb de HSPA Rab setup sur SFX4149F11 depuis 18/11
```

My goal is to take the three characters after the 'sur '.
I tried with this function. But in the result it appears empty.

```
delimiter |
CREATE FUNCTION METTRE(s VARCHAR(2000)) RETURNS varchar(2000)
DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN
           DECLARE open  INT;
           DECLARE close  INT;
           DECLARE someLimit  INT;
           DECLARE str  VARCHAR(2000);
           DECLARE toFind  VARCHAR(2000);
           DECLARE nom VARCHAR(20000);
           SET open = 1;
           SET close = 1;
           SET toFind = s ;
           SET someLimit = 100;
           SET str ='';
           WHILE close > 0 and open > 0 and someLimit > 0 DO
             SET someLimit = someLimit -1;
             SET open = locate('sur',toFind);
             IF open > 0 THEN
               SET toFind = SUBSTRING(toFind,open);
               SET close = locate(4,toFind);
               IF close > 2 THEN
                  SET nom=SUBSTRING(toFind,2,close-2);
                  SET toFind = SUBSTRING(toFind,close); 
               END IF;
             END IF;
           END WHILE;
           return SUBSTRING(str,2);

   END |
delimiter;
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are always looking for a 3 chars after `sur` and if there is a space after it it could be done more easily as

```
mysql> 
select 
substring(
 trim(
  substring_index(
    'Pb de HSPA Rab setup sur SFX4149F11 depuis 18/11','sur ',-1
  )
 ),
1,3) as n;
+-----+
| n   |
+-----+
| SFX |
+-----+
```

In the above just replace the hard-coded data with the column_name from the table

```
select 
substring(
 trim(
  substring_index(
    yor_col_name,'sur ',-1
  )
 ),
1,3) as n
```

From the comment looks like you are trying to update some other column in the same table, so here is an example how you can do it

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| val                                              | Affected_CI |
+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Pb de HSPA Rab setup sur SFX4149F11 depuis 18/11 | NULL        |
| Pb de HSPA Rab setup sur LJK4149F11 depuis 18/11 | NULL        |
| Pb de HSPA Rab setup sur MSP4149F11 depuis 18/11 | NULL        |
+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+


mysql> update test set Affected_CI = substring(trim(substring_index(val,'sur ',-1)),1,3) ;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| val                                              | Affected_CI |
+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Pb de HSPA Rab setup sur SFX4149F11 depuis 18/11 | SFX         |
| Pb de HSPA Rab setup sur LJK4149F11 depuis 18/11 | LJK         |
| Pb de HSPA Rab setup sur MSP4149F11 depuis 18/11 | MSP         |
+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: 'Pb de HSPA Rab setup sur SFX4149F11 depuis 18/11' is a field of a column but i would like  to run it on all the column.

Comment: Yes you can just repace that with the column name.

Comment: thanks.now , i tried to insert the result  with :                                                                          "INSERT INTO  incident (Affected_CI) VALUES (select     substring(trim(substring_index(Title,'sur ',-1)),1,3) as n from incident)"     but no result

Comment: @nabil123456: If the `title` value does not have a `'sur '` literal as part of it, the `substring_index` returns the input string, i.e. value of `title` column, as is.

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty , i tried to insert the result of command in a colomn named 'Affected_CI'  by using:  "INSERT INTO incident (Affected_CI) VALUES (select substring(trim(substring_index(Title,'sur ',-1)),1,3) as n from incident)" but no result

Comment: No you are doing wrong it should be update not insert its on the same table `incident`